# Generating the subset of a larger set, based on a seed

Tags: random, set

I need to implement a quiz generator, that based on the same input (seed), generates the same set of questions.

I would like to know how can I select elements from a set in a way that:

- The same elements are selected from the same seed every time
- Different seeds generate different results
- One element is selected only once per seed

## Example

Original, large set

- [Easy] Question 1
- [Easy] Question 2
- [Easy] Question 3
- [Easy] Question 4
- [Easy] Question 5
- [Easy] Question 6
- [Medium] Question 7
- [Medium] Question 8
- [Medium] Question 9
- [Medium] Question 10
- [Hard] Question 11
- [Hard] Question 12
- [Hard] Question 13

Using seed 1 (something like: 75163481528374) results in

- [Easy] Question 2
- [Easy] Question 3
- [Easy] Question 6
- [Medium] Question 7
- [Medium] Question 10
- [Hard] Question 11

Using seed 2 (something like: 63566663224223) results in

- [Easy] Question 2
- [Medium] Question 7
- [Medium] Question 8
- [Medium] Question 9
- [Medium] Question 10
- [Hard] Question 11
- [Hard] Question 13

After I have figured out the solution to the problem above, I would like to be able to control which percent of each category should the results contain, but I guess I can apply the algorithm to subsets created from categories.

I would like to implement the problem in Excel or C# but I don't think that this is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Organize the questions into separate arrays by category.
2. Use your random number generator to [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) each of the arrays.
3. Select the desired number (or percentage) of questions from the beginning of each of the shuffled arrays.

If your implementation language doesn't have a shuffle capability built-in, the Fisher-Yates algorithm is only [a few lines of code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) and gives you complete assurance that the seeding of random number generator is going straight to the shuffling procedure so you won't have any surprises.

Comment: The sorting idea is simple and nice. How do I encode that shuffling pattern into a seed? I need to shuffle the items based on a row of numeric characters

Comment: The seed is used by the RNG that determines the shuffle.  Same seed -> same random number sequence -> same shuffle.

Comment: By the way, shuffling is not sorting, in fact it's pretty much the opposite. Plus it only takes O(n) time to shuffle n items so it's quite efficient.